# ListView row not selectable

Tags: android, listview, colors

I have ListView inside music player (not ListActivity) and I tried I think everything on stackoverflow and after click on item, row is still not in another color. This is my code for ListView:

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/myMusicList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#242424"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selectorr"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" 
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

This is my list selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"  
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
</selector>
```

and the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:focusable="false">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:color="#f3f3f3"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code:

```
    ListView musicListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myMusicList);
    musicListView.setSelection(1);
    musicListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

....

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData, R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] { R.id.songTitle });
    musicListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    musicListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            playSong(position);
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
```

I have no idea what's wrong - I tried "singleChoice", changed selector in another colors, edited focusable and many more...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light""/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on my device: Nexus 7 with 4.3. Please provide your environment...

Comment: It's Jelly bean 4.0.4 and some "no name" tablet

Comment: Is it ok that selector calls `list_selectorr` here `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selectorr"`?

Comment: I tried to call it from code `musicListView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selectorr);` but it's the same...

Comment: Try reproduce on emulator, it seems something wrong with your device. Sorry that couldn't help more...